# Repeat alarm after two weeks

Tags: android

I want to repeat alarm after two weeks. I implemented following code to repeat alarm but it is not exactly repeating alarm after two weeks.

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 14, sender);`
```

can someone help me that how can i repeat alarm exactly after 14 days.

Comment: What is happening? Never execute your alarm?

Comment: it executes alarm but it the alarm is in the same month then it executes properly after two weeks but if the month change to the next month then it is repeating it after 15 days. That is the problem i am facing

Answer (score 0):

Use [pendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 14,pendingIntent);
```

Comment: it will repeat alarm after 7 days?

Comment: i am using the same code but sometime it repeats alarm after 14 days or some time after 15 days?

Comment: Did you try using calendar.getTimeInMillis(), see the edit

Comment: yes Tony, I tried the same. but the problem i am facing is :- if the alarm is in the same month then it repeats it correctly after two weeks but if same alarm goes to next month then it executes it after 15 days. That's the problem i am facing.

Answer (score 0):

Its not ideal to use `AlarmManager` for these kind of requests since, the system will not honor these requests once the phone reboots or the user force-stops your app. Anyway, among other things firstly you need to put up a `receiver` that listens for `BOOT_COMPLETE` events where you have to reset the alarm (after recalculating the remaining time).

Comment: right!! I know that but how can repeat alarm after 2 weeks exactly